# C++: Trying to use ctime to make a resetable clock in a console, but

Tags: c++, console, clock

I tried using ctime to make a clock that is resetable in a console, but for some reason, my code does not reset the time. After pressing the trigger button to reset the clock, the result is a weird number, rather than 0;

The code looks something like this:

```
clock_t time = 0;
clock_t corrected = 0;

while(true) //event-driven loop
{
time = clock();
std::cout<<"clock: " << time - corrected << std::endl;

if( /*Key is press*/) corrected = clock();
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this will solve your problem, but try using a different variable name other than time.

Comment: the actual one used something like current_time, and corrected_time, still encounter the same problem.../

Comment: What code are you using to test if the key is pressed?

Comment: ReadConsoleInput from WinCon in windows header, the actual one is lengthy and unorganized, so I didn't post it here

Comment: Why is `corrected` initialized to 0? I would expect it to be initialized to `clock()` just before the `while`-loop starts.

Nevertheless, have you tried to check the return values of `clock()`? `-1` indicates an error and might result in rather large numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If I do this:

```
while(true) //event-driven loop
{
    time = clock();
    std::cout<<"clock: " << time - corrected << std::endl;

    if( GetAsyncKeyState('A') & 0x8000 )
        corrected = clock();
}
```

The output resets to 0 everytime I press the `A` key.  The problem is with your keypress testing.